# Smart way of processing list with threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a list of **read only** data which are a bunch of end points on the internet that I want to process. I was wondering is there any kind of built in class or pattern that I should follow to process this ?

Right now I'm just diving the initial list into *N* blocks and creating *N* threads to process each request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any reason why you can't use the appropriate concurrent container? http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html

Comment: +1 ConcurrentLinkedQueue is my "first choice" for passing off data between threads (at least within a primitive threading model).

Answer (score 4):

Use an [ExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to handle your concurrent processing.

```
public void processAll(List<Endpoint> endpoints, int numThreads) {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);

    for(final Endpoint endpoint : endpoints) {
        executor.submit(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doProcessing(endpoint);
            }
        });
    }
    // instead of a loop, you could also use ExecutorService#invokeAll()
    // with the passed-in list if Endpoint implements
    // java.util.concurrent.Callable

    executor.shutdown();
}

private void doProcessing(Endpoint endpoint) {
    // do whatever you do with each one
}
```

This is just a bare-bones example. Have a look at the API for some examples about how to use a more specific type of `ExecutorService`, handle [`Futures`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html), and do all kinds of nifty stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a [`Queue`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) (use one of the implementations in `java.util.concurrent`) is what you need. That way each thread can pick up a link when it's ready, which makes more sense than partitioning in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You will need three thinks:

- two blocking list - first with data to porcess, second for results
- Executor service
- some kind of latch

My example application:

```
public class App {

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        BlockingQueue<String> data = prepareData();

        BlockingQueue<String> results = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(3);

        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; i++)
            executor.execute(new Processor<String>(data, results,
                    countDownLatch, i + ""));

        countDownLatch.await();
    }

    private static BlockingQueue<String> prepareData() {
        BlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            queue.add(i + "");
        }
        return queue;
    }

}

class Processor<T> implements Runnable {

    private BlockingQueue<T> dataSource;

    private CountDownLatch latch;

    private String name;

    private BlockingQueue<String> results;

    public Processor(BlockingQueue<T> dataSource,
            BlockingQueue<String> results, CountDownLatch countDownLatch,
            String processName) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.results = results;
        this.latch = countDownLatch;
        this.name = processName;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        T t = null;
        while ((t = dataSource.poll()) != null) {
            try {
                String result = "Process " + name + " processing: "
                        + t.toString();
                System.out.println(result);
                results.put(result);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        latch.countDown();
    }
}
```

After prepare data create some *Processors* to process data. Each *processor* have reference to thread save data source. Get Object, process them and finally put result to another thread save collection that contains results.

When data source go empty then call *latch.countDown()* to say "everything done" to main thread or thread that wait for results.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the java.util.concurrent package and the ExecutorService.

Brian Goetz's book Java Concurrency in Practice is a must to understand this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Blocking Queues are probably the best way to go for you. Google it and you'll find plenty of info, this for one is a good tutorial:http://www.developer.com/java/ent/article.php/3645111/Java-5s-BlockingQueue.htm